# Cakephp Find operation unknown field error

Tags: sql, cakephp, join

I have 2 tables

A Prison table and a Warden table.
A Prison can have several Wardens scheduled to work for the prison.
Warden records have start date and end date fields the time range that they will work for a Prison.

I have set up an association, which is Prison hasMany Warden.
Warden table has a foreign key field prison_id.

If i do a $this->Warden->find('all');

I will get all Prisons, with all their Wardens scheduled for the past and future.

I only want to get Wardens working for a Prison for a particular date.

I'm trying to do something like

```
    $searchfilter = array(
                        'Warden.startdate <=' => $date,
                        'Warden.enddate   >=' => $date,
                        );        

    return $this->Prison->find('all', array('conditions' => $searchfilter));
```

But this results in unknown field error.

Comment: Be more specific with the error, what field is unknown? Also, you are probably getting the error because you aren't containing the Warden model, have you set  recursion to -1?

Comment: can you mention your model codes for Warden and Prison? and make sure there is startdate and enddate is found in wardens table? and also I don't think conditions Warden inside prison find will work unless Prison belongsTo Warden in the model

Comment: The error is Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Warden.startdate' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 1):

Your find is on the Prison model, but your condition is on the Warden model, which is why it's giving the unknown field error.  That query would work if you simply did the following instead:

```
return $this->Prison->Warden->find('all', array('conditions' => $searchfilter));
```

If you want a specific prison, if you know its id, you can simply add to your $searchFilter

```
'Warden.prison_id' => $id
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying blind.... `Warden.prison_id` is not present on your prisons table.. To make it simple use Containable behavior...

### Prison.php

```
class Prison extends AppModel{
    public $hasMany = array('Warden');

    public $actsAs = array('Containable');// adding behaviors to model

    public function getPrison(){
        $searchfilter = array(
                            'Warden.startdate <=' => $date,
                            'Warden.enddate   >=' => $date,
                            );

        $data = $this->find('all', array(
                                    'contain' => array(
                                        'Warden' => array(
                                            'conditions' => $searchfilter
                                        )
                                    )
        ));

        return $data;

    }
}
```